# Realm Cocoa: Potential threading / notifications issue (or i am missing something from the docs)

Tags: realm

I've been hitting an issue for the past two days which i cannot find a solution for...

Let's imagine we have the following method - which basically generates some fixture realm data:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [DataManager me].realm;
    
    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        [realm deleteObjects:[self realmQuery]];
    }];
    
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
       // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            RLMRealm *realm = [[DataManager me] defaultRealmInstance];
            
            [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
                for (NSInteger j = 1; j<= 9;j++) {
                    VEventListRealmModel *b = [VEventListRealmModel new];
                    b.sid = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%ld", i, j] integerValue];
                    [realm addObject:b];
                }
            }];
       // });
    }
```

b.sid - is a primary int key.

Now let's also connect a notification block listener like this:

```
self.eventsToken = [self.events addNotificationBlock:^(RLMResults* _Nullable results, RLMCollectionChange * _Nullable change, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"insertions: %@", change.insertions);
        return;
```

In which we will log all the inserts which happen with the above method.

Now - if we run the method within the main thread (GCD method commented) - there is no issue, what is printed in the console is:

```
2020-11-20 16:22:45.305592+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.308726+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.311453+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.313953+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    27,
    28,
    29,
    30,
    31,
    32,
    33,
    34,
    35
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.316284+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    36,
    37,
    38,
    39,
    40,
    41,
    42,
    43,
    44
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.318469+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    45,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    51,
    52,
    53
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.320953+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    54,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    60,
    61,
    62
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.323501+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    63,
    64,
    65,
    66,
    67,
    68,
    69,
    70,
    71
)
2020-11-20 16:22:45.326177+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13639:1766934] insertions: (
    72,
    73,
    74,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80
)
```

But then if we enable the GCD method which in effect makes 10 background threads in which we do the inserts here is what happens:

```
2020-11-20 16:23:52.741126+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.749824+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.761401+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.764369+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.774132+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    27,
    28,
    29,
    30,
    31,
    32,
    33,
    34,
    35
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.779910+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    36,
    37,
    38,
    39,
    40,
    41,
    42,
    43,
    44
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.784659+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    45,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    51,
    52,
    53
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.790541+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    45,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    51,
    52,
    53
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.794565+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    63,
    64,
    65,
    66,
    67,
    68,
    69,
    70,
    71
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.800134+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    72,
    73,
    74,
    75,
    76,
    77,
    78,
    79,
    80
)
```

As you see the indexes of the changes collection get duplicated:

```
2020-11-20 16:23:52.761401+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17
)
2020-11-20 16:23:52.764369+0200 VIPFitterBeta[13733:1768828] insertions: (
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17
)
```

Why is this happening?

My understanding is that the notification listener - as it is initialized on the main thread it will get syncrhonized when the background threads finish their work and we would receive only unique 'change indexes' - as we do if this was done on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Kovachev Realm will batch up the changes made on the background thread and then deliver them to the notifier. It is possible that you are receiving changes before the Realm has advanced it's version. I have a few questions:

- Where are you instantiating the notification block? Is it in the loop?
- Which version of Realm are you using?
- After all of the write transactions have completed, can you query the `VEventListRealmModel` object and verify there are 81 objects and no duplicates?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am registering the hook on the UI thread, realm is latest ver. The issue is not that i am experiencing duplicate objects - but the order of the indexes is being duplicated - but please read below as i've figured out why :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i am misunderstanding how realm changes are being tracked in the notification block.

My initial understanding (or misunderstanding) was that the updated indexes are unique numbers.

For example if we have an array of 5 items (creating and inserting them) and we update each one of them (say 1 update of an object on a new background thread) - i expected that the notification block will see indexes 0,1,2,3,4 of the updated objects.

But it turns out this is not true! What happens is - because background threads are inserting they can compete for the inserts and instead of receiving 0,1,2,3,4 indexes sometimes i see 0,1,2,2,3 for example.

This basically means realm is not always appending the new data at the end of the array - it can actually insert within already existing indexes.

And it makes sense... it should depend on the actual initial realm query which was used to load the objects and register the notification listener...

If UITables are used as in the realm examples within a notification block this works just fine as the table is interested in the total count of objects available and then lazily displaying each one of them.

But in my logic i do not use a table view to represent the data - but to update various internal array objects which depend on the uniqueness of this update index... which was my logical mistake and now i'll have to find a way to rework this without relying on the indexes.

Hope i've explained it properly and it helps someone else too :)